# TypeError at /add_racion/ bel() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self' в django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

У меня есть 3 класса: Блюда, прием пищи и связующий класс блюдо+прием пищи. В связующем классе есть 4 поля, которые должны автоматически вычисляться: bel, jir, ugl, cal. Но django всячески препятствует этому и выдает ошибку:

> File "D:\Мои проекты\eda\bjuk\models.py", line 33, in bel
>       b = (gramm/100.0)*food.bel TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'FloatField' and 'float'

Вроде все логично - FloatField и float, но django не нравится. Я пытался сделать вычисления для этих полей в формах, но безуспешно(если интересно, то в моем профиле есть вопрос, где вычисления производятся в формах).

models.py

```
class Food(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Название')
    bel = models.FloatField(verbose_name='Белки')
    jir = models.FloatField(verbose_name='Жиры')
    ugl = models.FloatField(verbose_name='Углеводы')
    cal = models.FloatField(verbose_name='Калории')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Еда'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Meal(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=65, verbose_name='Название приема пищи')
    time = models.TimeField(verbose_name='Время приема', blank=False)
    foods = models.ManyToManyField(Food, through='Racion', through_fields=('meal', 'food'))

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

## Старая версия

```
class Racion(models.Model):
    meal = models.ForeignKey(Meal, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    food = models.ForeignKey(Food, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    gramm = models.FloatField(verbose_name='Грамм')
    def bel(food, gramm):
        b = (gramm/100)*food.bel
        return b
    bel = models.FloatField(default=bel(food, gramm), blank=True)
    def jir(food, gramm):
        j = (gramm/100)*food.jir
        return j
    jir = models.FloatField(default=jir(food, gramm), blank=True)
    def ugl(food, gramm):
        u = (gramm/100)*food.ugl
        return u
    ugl = models.FloatField(default=ugl(food, gramm), blank=True)
    def cal(food, gramm):
        c = (gramm/100)*food.cal
        return c
    cal = models.FloatField(default=cal(food, gramm), blank=True)
```

## Новая версия

```
class Racion(models.Model):
    meal = models.ForeignKey(Meal, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    food = models.ForeignKey(Food, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    gramm = models.FloatField(verbose_name='Грамм')
    def bel(self):
        b = (self.gramm/100.0)*self.food.bel
        return b
    belki = models.FloatField(default=bel, blank=True)
    def jir(self):
        j = (self.gramm/100.0)*self.food.jir
        return j
    jiri = models.FloatField(default=jir, blank=True)
    def ugl(self):
        u = (self.gramm/100.0)*self.food.ugl
        return u
    uglevodi = models.FloatField(default=ugl, blank=True)
    def cal(self):
        c = (self.gramm/100.0)*self.food.cal
        return c
    calori = models.FloatField(default=cal, blank=True)
```

Исправил код моделей как сказали в комментариях, теперь выдает ошибку:

> TypeError at /add_racion
>   bel() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Comment: Вы должны обращаться к значению поля через `self` (будет передан первым аргументом в функцию автоматически).

Comment: А ещё у вас поля и методы имеют одинаковые имена, в результате чего объявленное позже имя затирает объявленное ранее. Вам бы учебник по Python почитать какой-нибудь.

Comment: @nomnoms12 добавил self, но теперь в поле модели он запрашивает 1 аргумент